# Is there a conventional order to write commutative parts of an expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, article-writing, convention

This stemmed from an office discussion. Often when writing expressions, it feels like there is a more natural way to write parts of an expression that are commutative. For instance, it seems as though it would be more natural to write $$e^{x}(\sin{(x)}+2)$$ rather than the equally correct $$(\sin{(x)}+2)e^{x},$$
which I have only seen rarely.

Is there a set of agreed-upon "rules" somewhere for a conventional way of writing maths, or is it a cultural thing depending on the background you have/field you're in?

Comment: I don't see any reason to prefer $e^x(\sin x+2)$ to $(\sin x+2)e^x$.

Comment: Most people tend to write the first one, but that doesn't make the second one "wrong".

Comment: @K.defaoite I agree, I just wondered if there were any agreed-upon conventions anywhere. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the ISO standards for typesetting mathematics and there doesn't appear to be anything on the order of commutative expressions. So, no, there isn't (or at least if there is, it's by a different organisation entirely).